# PHP cURL not working with proxy on live server

Tags: php, curl, proxy

I want to execute this code on local server. It gives the response, but when I try to run the same code on live stage server, it returns a 404 error.

```
$url = "http://www.google.com/search?q=saree&num=100&start=0&pws=0";
$name = $name;

$encoded = $url.$name;

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, '111.119.226.129');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT,'80');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
$exec = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

I use random valid proxies for this code, and I'm sure the proxy is valid.

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: disable the server firewall will solve the problem

Answer (score 2):

add these to your code and try

```
$url = "http://www.google.com/search?q=saree&num=100&start=0&pws=0";
$name = $name;

$encoded = $url.$name;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; rv:1.7.3) Gecko/20041001 Firefox/0.10.1");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers); //set headers
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); // set true for https urls
```

Comment: you should try this code for finding errors. error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);