# php- curl isn't working for POST requests

Tags: php, http, post, curl

I want to send a POST request using curl but don't know why it isn't working. The  HTTP request is as:

**Type**: POST
**URL**: https://abc.com/server/386594/actions/?do=open
**HEADERS**: Authorization: Basic 1234abc

When I am make request using curl (CLI) then it works fine but in php I do not get any response. My code is:

```
$headers = array("Authorization: Basic 1234abc");
$ch1 = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_URL, "https://abc.com/server/386594/actions/");
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch1, CUTLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "do=open");
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$vnc = curl_exec($ch1);
echo $vnc;
echo curl_error($ch1);
```

Where am I wrong? :)

Comment: No response ? not even an error ? Curl is enabled in Php?

Comment: possible duplicate of [php curl not working with proxy on live server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20239364/php-curl-not-working-with-proxy-on-live-server)

Comment: @Abhinav no response. no error. and yes curl works fine for other post & get rrquests so its enabled.

Comment: @Manish Jesani I dont think i am using proxy

Comment: try $headers = array("Authorization:Basic 1234abc"); instead of $headers = array("Authorization: Basic 1234abc"); remove space after ":"

Comment: dump the $_SERVER variable on your target .php file and look, if all variables was send.

Comment: duplicate issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15151739/curl-post-not-working-php

Answer (score 1):

Please put the code as below....

url is not secure url, so that remove the HTTPS and write simple HTTP.

```
$headers = array("Authorization:Basic 1234abc");
                            //remove the space
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$host_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,true);
                                    //remove 1 and put 'true' keyword
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"do=open");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_DIGEST);
    $curl_response = curl_exec($ch);
```